# How can I show my navbar horizontally without affecting the background img and hero content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a landing page but I'm finding it hard to place my navbar and still keep my hero content intact the way it is. I tried using flexbox but it seems it's not working when I position my content relative and use bottom 50% to bring the nave bar to the corner.

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.hero-image {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("building.jpg");
    height: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.hero-text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
}

.btn {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border-color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: aqua  ;
    border-color: aqua;
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="hero-image">
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1>Welcome to ZERG</h1>
          <p>Where we Strive for a better Future</p>
          <button class="btn">Find out More</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <nav class="main">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

      
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean a bottom navbar? Or a weird horizontally in the middle one? Here is an example of bottom navbar. Run the snippet and put in full page.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("building.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.btn {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border-color: white;
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  border-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h1>Welcome to ZERG</h1>
      <p>Where we Strive for a better Future</p>
      <button class="btn">Find out More</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bottom navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropup">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://getbootstrap.com/" id="dropdown10" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropup</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown10">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: I was looking to have the navigation bar at the top left hand corner.

Comment: I cant really pinpoint what kind of navbar are you trying to achieve. But here are some useful links to get you started. With demos and all.
[Horizontal Navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar_horizontal.asp)
[Vertical Navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar_vertical.asp)
[Using Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)